# cannot add multiple textbox values in html and jq

Tags: jquery, html

sir i have 10 text boxes .1st two take values from user and display the multiplication result on 3rd text box when it clicked.4th and 5th textboxes also take values and display the multiplication result in 6th text box when it clicked. like same as above 7th and 8th textbox will work accordingly and 9th textbox will display the multiplication result when it clicked.10th textbox takes the values from 3rd  6th and 9th textbox and add them. my problem is that i can do the multiplication bt cannot display the total sum in 10th  textbox  in html and jscript.plz help me.....i am attached the code...

my code

```
<script >
function getext3(){
txt1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;
document.getElementById("text3").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);

} 

function getext6(){
txt1 = document.getElementById("text4").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text5").value;
document.getElementById("text6").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);

} 

function getext9(){
txt1 = document.getElementById("text7").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text8").value;
document.getElementById("text9").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);

} 


function getext10(){


txt1 = document.getElementById("text3").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text6").value;
txt3 = document.getElementById("text9").value;
txt4 = parseInt(txt1)+parseInt(txt2)+parseInt(txt3);
document.getElementById("text7").value = txt4; 

} 
</script>

Text1 : <input type="text"value="0" id="text1" value=""> <br/>
Text2 : <input type="text" value="0"id="text2" value=""> <br/>
Text3 : <input type="text"value="0"id="text3" value="0" onclick="getext3()"> <br/>


Text4 : <input type="text"value="0"id="text4" value=""> <br/>
Text5 : <input type="text" value="0"id="text5" value=""> <br/>
Text6 : <input type="text" id="text6" value="0" onclick="getext6()"> <br/>


Text7 : <input type="text"value="0"id="text7" value=""> <br/>
Text8 : <input type="text" value="0"id="text8" value=""> <br/>
Text9 : <input type="text" id="text9" value="0" onclick="getext9()"> <br/>

Text10 : <input type="text" id="text10" value="" onclick="getext10()"> <br/>
```

Comment: __A Typo__ `document.getElementById("text10").value = txt4;` http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/pymutodh/

Comment: Last line of total function you need `document.getElementById("text10").value = txt4;` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r007p3xk/)

Answer (score 1):

Update

`document.getElementById("text7").value = txt4;`

To

`document.getElementById("text10").value = txt4;`

in **function getext10()**

Here is a **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/hLwsr94g/)**